# How to read from a file & store key:value pair in String Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a coffee script file with the following data in it. I want to create a string array that will store the following data as key:value pair in it.

```
abTests:
    productRanking:
      version: 4
      groups: [
        ratio:
          default: 1
          us: 0.90
          me: 0.0
        value: "LessPopularityEPC"
      ,
        ratio:
          default: 0
          us: 0.1
        value: "CtrEpcJob"
      ,
        ratio:
          default: 0
          me: 1.0
        value: "RandomPerVisitor"
      ]
    sabt:
      version: 1
      groups: [
        ratio:
          default: 1
          us: 0.90
        value: "default"
      ,
        ratio:
          default: 0
          us: 0.05
        value: "colorBoost"
      ,
        ratio:
          default: 0
          us: 0.05
        value: "colorPriority"
      ,
        ratio:
          default: 0
          us: 0
        value: "noColorClause"
      ]
```

I want to create a String Array with these data in the following format

```
productRanking:LessPopularityEPC
productRanking:CtrEpcJob
productRanking:RandomPerVisitor
sabt:default
sabt:colorboost
sabt:colorPriority
sabt:nocolorClause
```

Is there any way to solve this problem??

Comment: Instead of trying to parse CoffeeScript in Ruby, why don't you do it in CoffeeScript? Or in Node.js with one of the CSON modules?

Comment: @Jordan I have to generate all possible combinations of key:value pair in order to automate these tests. I need to get the solution in Ruby only. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Why do you need a Ruby-only solution? If you're working in Rails then you almost certainly have access to a JavaScript interpreter so why not use it? Correctly parsing CSON is probably harder than you think.

Answer (score 1):

If by String Array you mean this

```
['productRanking:LessPopularityEPC', 'productRanking:CtrEpcJob', 'productRanking:RandomPerVisitor']
```

You can do that with the following coffeescript code

```
data = abTests:
  ...

array = []
for testName,tests of data['abTests']
  for categoryName,categoryElems of tests['groups']
    array.push (testName + ':' + categoryElems['value'])

console.log array
#=> ['productRanking:LessPopularityEPC', 'productRanking:CtrEpcJob', 'productRanking:RandomPerVisitor']
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Appreciate it. But, I have multiple keys like that. I meant to say my data further scales like this

`productRanking:LessPopularityEPC
productRanking:CtrEpcJob
productRanking:RandomPerVisitor
sabt:helloworld
sabt:goworld
mouseenter:true
mouseenter:false`

Is there any way that will fetch the key ?

Comment: I have added further data from the file & the solution that I required. It would be great if you could help me with that

Comment: Could you please provide me Ruby solution ?

Comment: Could you please help me with this solution?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565007/why-i-am-not-getting-right-value-when-pushing-it-to-an-array?noredirect=1#comment58818618_35565007